# Magento 1.9.1.0 on Ubuntu 14.04 change order # from 9 digits (standard) to 5 digits

Tags: magento, magento-1.9, magento-1.9.1

Title says it all, I would really appreciate it!
at this moment, Magento generates a order # with 9 digits. 
100000001 for example, I'd like it to be 10001

I want to use the order # for promotional purposes, so you know why I need it. :)

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this you can execute this code:

```
$entityType = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_type')->loadByCode('order');
$entityType->setIncrementPadLength(5)->save();
```

Alternatively you can execute a query on the magento DB

```
UPDATE `eav_entity_type` SET `increment_pad_length`=5 WHERE entity_type_code = 'order';
```

Comment: 8 years ago already.. time flies.

I just noticed this after coming back to Stack Overflow for something else. Just wanted to let you know that I really appreciate your effort in giving me a great answer.